# Как в php в html встроить инструкцию elseif

Tags: php, html, wordpress, шаблоны

не работает конструкция не принимает elseif БЕЗ ELSE все работает

```
<?phpif (get_post_meta($post->ID, 'close_quest', true)==false ) : ?>
       <div id="stars">.........</div>
    <? elseif; ?>
      <div id="link">.........</div>
    <? endif; ?>
```

Как быть мне в if и else нуно встроить большие html строки

Так тоже работает ну немного хотелось бы по компактней

```
<?php if (get_post_meta($post->ID, 'close_quest', true)==false ) : ?>
        <div id="stars">.........</div>
        <? elseif (get_post_meta($post->ID, 'close_quest', true)==true ) : ?>
            <div id="link">.........</div>
        <? endif; ?>
```

Comment: Для этого надо сначала понимать, для чего тебе вообще нужeн elseif. Как только ты сам поймешь, что хочешь сделать, проблема решится сама собой

Comment: Хм у меня проверка по произвольному полю истина/ложь в Вордпресс

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[else if](http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.elseif.php) нужно условие внутри скобок, а у вас ; ( и отделите if от начального тега php )
пример :

```
<?php if (get_post_meta($post->ID, 'close_quest', true)==false ) { ?>
   <div id="stars">.........</div>
<? } else if(1==1) {  ?> <!-- условие для примера -->
  <div id="link">.........</div>
<? } ?>
```

ecли вам не нужна дополнительная проверка в elseif можно поставить else, пример ниже :

```
<?php if (get_post_meta($post->ID, 'close_quest', true)==false ) { ?>
   <div id="stars">.........</div>
<? } else {  ?>
  <div id="link">.........</div>
<? } ?>
```

Comment: <?phpif (get_post_meta($post->ID, 'close_quest', true)==false ) : ?>
       <div id="stars">.........</div>
     <? endif; ?> этот коадд прекрасно отрабатывает

Comment: Спасибо отлично работает